# How to send another email after verifying registration mail in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-blade

[image]
Laravel community i want to send another email with user cardentials when i click verify email button.
Anyone have any idea? How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 ways to do this:

1. You may override the `verified` method on `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController` class to do whatever you want to do after user's email address is verified:

   ```php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
   use Illuminate\Http\Response;

   class VerificationController extends Controller
   {
       //...

       /**
        * The user has been verified.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @return mixed
        */
       protected function verified(Request $request)
       {
           //TODO: send another email as you want!

           return $request->wantsJson()
                       ? new Response('', 204)
                       : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you may attach a listener to `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified` event in your `EventServiceProvider`

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/verification#events) for more info.